# Does not getting build failure status even the build not successful run(cloud-build remote builder)

Tags: bash, exception, error-handling, google-cloud-build

Cloud-build is not showing build failure status

I created my own remote-builder which **scp** all files from **/workspace** to my **Instance** and running build on using **gcloud compute ssh -- COMMAND**
[remote-builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/remote-builder)

```
#!/bin/bash 
USERNAME=${USERNAME:-admin}
REMOTE_WORKSPACE=${REMOTE_WORKSPACE:-/home/${USERNAME}/workspace/}
GCLOUD=${GCLOUD:-gcloud}


KEYNAME=builder-key
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f ${KEYNAME} -C ${USERNAME} || true
chmod 400 ${KEYNAME}*

cat > ssh-keys <<EOF
${USERNAME}:$(cat ${KEYNAME}.pub)
EOF

${GCLOUD} compute scp --compress --recurse \
       $(pwd)/ ${USERNAME}@${INSTANCE_NAME}:${REMOTE_WORKSPACE} \
       --ssh-key-file=${KEYNAME}

${GCLOUD} compute ssh --ssh-key-file=${KEYNAME} \
       ${USERNAME}@${INSTANCE_NAME} -- ${COMMAND}
```

below is the example of the code to run build(*cloudbuild.yaml*)

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/remote-builder
  env:
    - COMMAND="docker build -t [image_name]:[tagname] -f Dockerfile ."
```

During docker build inside Dockerfile it got failure and show errors in log but status showing **SUCCESS**

can any help me how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share the output of the logs? That would be helpful in order to provide you with an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote all docker commands on bash script and add below error handling code to it.

```
handle_error() {
    echo "FAILED: line $1, exit code $2"
    exit 1
}
trap 'handle_error $LINENO $?' ERR
```

It works!

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
|| exit 1
```

at the end of your docker command... alternatively, you might just need to change the entrypoint to 'bash' and run the script manually

To confirm -- the first part was the run-on.sh script, and the second part was your cloudbuild.yaml right? I assume you trigger the build manually via UI and/or REST API?